# How do I add a private python package to cloud composer's requirements?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to install a private python package in the Google Cloud composer environment. I usually install the package using a personal access token. That works with usual pip.

`pip install git+https://$TOKEN@github.com/org/repo.git@main`

works as expected. However, trying to use this in Cloud Composer tells me the following:

> PyPI package name must follow the format of 'identifier' specified in PEP-508. (https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/)

I'm not sure what I should do here. Does anyone have some experience with this?

Comment: Did you consider building a container and run it with a KubernetesPodOperator?

Answer (score 3):

If the repo hosting your private Python packages accepts external calls, you can generate a `pip.conf` file with params to access to this repo :

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://username:password@yourrepo.com/simple
```

Then you have to copy this file to Cloud Composer bucket : `{composer_bucket_name}/config/pip/pip.conf`

You can also host your Python private packages in `GCP Artifact registry`, then generate a `pip.conf` file allowed to access to the created Python repo in Artifact registry and then copy this file to the Composer bucket : `{composer_bucket_name}/config/pip/pip.conf`

After this you can add your private Python Packages in the PyPi packages list from Cloud Composer, like public packages :

[image: Composer PyPi Packages]

You can also check this link from official documentation : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies

Comment: Hi @Vinay, have you solved your issue ?

Comment: How do you handle a situation where an internal package published on Artifact Registry has the same name as another package published on the public PyPI registry? How can you distinguish packages in such cases?