# Structure Folder Path with Repository path Cloud Composer DAG

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I need to run the DAG with the repository folder name, and I need to call the other modules from another directory from another path repository deployed.

So, I have a `cloudbuild.yaml` that will deploy the script into DAG folder and Plugins folder, but I still didn't know, how to get the other modules from the other path on Cloud Composer Bucket Storage.

This is my Bucket Storage path

```
cloud-composer-bucket/
    dags/
        github_my_repository_deployed-testing/
            test_dag.py
    plugins/
        github_my_repository_deployed-testing/
            planning/
                modules_1.py
```

I need to call `modules_1.py` from my `test_dag.py`, I used this command to call the module

```
from planning.modules_1 import get_data
```

But from this method, I got an error shown like this

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/github_my_repository_deployed-testing/test_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/github_my_repository_deployed-testing/test_dag.py", line 7, in <module>
    from planning.modules_1 import get_date
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'planning'
```

This is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- id: 'Push into Composer DAG'
  name: 'google/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: [ '-c', 'gsutil -m rsync -d -r ./dags ${_COMPOSER_BUCKET}/dags/$REPO_NAME']
- id: 'Push into Composer Plugins'
  name: 'google/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: [ '-c', 'gsutil -m rsync -d -r ./plugins ${_COMPOSER_BUCKET}/plugins/$REPO_NAME']
- id: 'Code Scanning'
  name: 'python:3.7-slim'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: [ '-c', 'pip install bandit && bandit --exit-zero -r ./']
substitutions:
    _CONTAINER_VERSION: v0.0.1
    _COMPOSER_BUCKET: gs://asia-southeast1-testing-cloud-composer-025c0511-bucket
```

My question is, what is the best and how to call the other modules into DAG?

Answer (score 3):

You can put every modules in the `Cloud Composer` `DAG` folder, example :

```
cloud-composer-bucket/
    dags/
        github_my_repository_deployed-testing/
            test_dag.py
        planning/
            modules_1.py
        
        setup.py
```

On the `DAG` `Python` code, you can import your module with the following way :

```py
from planning.modules_1 import get_data
```

As I remembered, the `setup.py` is created by `Cloud Composer` in the `DAG` root folder, if it's not the case, you can copy the `setup.py` in the `DAG` folder :

```
bucket/dags/setup.py
```

Example of `setup.py` file :

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="composer_env_python_lib",
    version="0.0.1",
    install_requires=[],
    data_files=[],
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

**Other possible solution**

You can also use internal `Python` packages from `GCP` `Artifact registry` if you want (example with your package `planning`).

Then you can download your internal `Python` `packages` from `Cloud Composer` via `PyPiPackages`, I share with you a link about this :

[private repo Composer Artifact registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403356/how-do-i-add-a-private-python-package-to-cloud-composers-requirements)

Comment: Thanks for the response, what is inside in `setup.py` ?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer to give you more information about the `setup.py` file. I also proposed you a second solution if you are interested.

Comment: Hey, thank you! So I'm curious here, why I can't import the python script from `Plugins` folder? If I read on this [Composer Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket), it was said `Stores your custom plugins, such as custom in-house Airflow operators, hooks, sensors, or interfaces.`

Comment: You're welcome. If you use custom `Airflow` operator, it's not an obligation to use the `Plugins` folder. You can also put your custom operators in your folder copied in the Airflow `dags` `bucket` folder, example : `{composer_bucket}/dags/your_dag_folder/operators`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but it got an error, what command to import from `[composer_bucket]/plugins/planning/modules_1.py`? I've used this `from plugins.planning import modules_1`, but it sent an error